# iOS Background Task in IOS 13 Not working

Tags: swift, ios13, background-task

Im trying to work on with iOS 13 background tasks to be executed and created the sample application as per apple says:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks/bgtaskscheduler

But some how im still getting error in console as:

```
Can't end BackgroundTask: no background task exists with identifier 1 (0x1), or it may have already been ended. Break in UIApplicationEndBackgroundTaskError() to debug.
```

And this seems like many are experiencing this issue:
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/121990

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The BGTasks worked fine with the new iOS 13.4 and i tried this on real device and it seemed working fine.
So the issue was it wasnt working on simulator but on device its fine.

I never tried this on other device, rather i just tried on device with iOS 13.4. Seems to be fine.